# ng-repeat and $scope issue

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a page displaying 3 images in a row, using Ng-repeat, but no matter which image I click, I only see the image of the FIRST image displayed in that specific row.

Template:

```
<div id="galscrolldiv" class="row" ng-repeat="image in images" ng-if="$index % 3 === 0">
    <div class="col col-33" ng-if="$index < images.length">
        <div ng-click="seeOne(image)">
            <img ng-src="{{images[$index].src}}" width="100%" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-33" ng-if="$index + 1 < images.length">
        <div ng-click="seeOne(image)">
            <img ng-src="{{images[$index + 1].src}}" width="100%" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-33" ng-if="$index + 2 < images.length">
        <div ng-click="seeOne(image)">
            <img ng-src="{{images[$index + 2].src}}" width="100%" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

ng-click function:

```
$scope.seeOne = function (image) {
    window.localStorage['fbid'] = image.fbid;
    $state.go('app.oneimg');
}
```

$scope.images:

```
angular.forEach(value, function (value, key) {
    if (key == 'photo') {
        $scope.images.push({
            id: i,
            fbid: inventorykey,
            src: ("data:image/jpeg;base64," + value)
        });
        i = i + 1;
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You're repeating `<div ng-click="seeOne(image)">` 3 times in this example, where `image` only refers to the first one of the 3 images you're displaying. If you change that line to match the `<img>` tag beneath it, you get the result you're looking for. Something like this:

```
<div id="galscrolldiv" class="row" ng-repeat="image in images" ng-if="$index % 3 === 0">
    <div class="col col-33" ng-if="$index < images.length">
        <div ng-click="seeOne(images[$index])">
            <img ng-src="{{images[$index].src}}" width="100%" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-33" ng-if="$index + 1 < images.length">
        <div ng-click="seeOne(images[$index+1])">
            <img ng-src="{{images[$index + 1].src}}" width="100%" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-33" ng-if="$index + 2 < images.length">
        <div ng-click="seeOne(images[$index+2])">
            <img ng-src="{{images[$index + 2].src}}" width="100%" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`{{images[$index].src}}` is wrong. use `{{image.src}}` instead.

The $index will change at each iteration, but there is only one variable. so at the end of the rendering all images will be the same as the refer to the same index. it doesn't matter what was the value when the page is rendered. It matters whats the value at the end of the angular digest phase.

To achieve your use case you need to set and use a local variable into the ng-repeat scope:

```
<div id="galscrolldiv" class="row" ng-repeat="image in images" ng-if="$index % 3 === 0" ng-init="myIndex = $index">
    <div class="col col-33" ng-if="$index < images.length">
        <div ng-click="seeOne(image)">
            <img ng-src="{{images[myIndex].src}}" width="100%" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Alternative: Put the data in the proper structure (an 2d array) and use nested `ng-repeat` - makes your life much easier

Comment: I think you need to re-evaluate the code. Each iteration of the ng-repeat loop is actually looping through 3 images, which are then accessed by `images[index]`, `images[index+1]`, and `images[index+2]`.